# Selenium Grid - Do something on test failure

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am relatively new to Selenium Grid and I'm having issues with test stability. For some reason, when I'm running my tests via the grid and RemoteWebDriver, my tests intermittently get stuck on the IEDriverServer opening page that says,

`"This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."`

This causes the remainder of the tests that get put against that machine to fail, which is extremely frustrating because 99 times out of 100 those same tests will pass on a rerun.

I am wanting to do something like the following but can't seem to implement it. Here is the pseudo code:

```
if(initialWebDriverPageTextIsOnPage > 30seconds)
{    
    driver.Close();
    driver.Dispose();
}
```

I feel like this could fit in my basetest as a listener that consistently polls the page but I can't seem to figure out how to implement this.

Any advice, or suggestions as to what the root cause is would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As an advice I can suggest to enable all the logs (node, hub, driver, client and try to understand the root cause of the problem).

Comment: Probably it can appear due to unstable connection between hub and node. Btw, how long tests will hang before failing with timeout exception? And could you please provide the full stack trace of that error?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It usually hangs for exactly 1 minute before the test times out. I added an explicit wait in the page loading and it seems to have possibly solved the issue. Maybe the page was trying to interact with elements before they were loaded. I'll come back with a solution if this fixes it, otherwise I'll provide the stack trace and we can move on from there.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to wait for your intended url to wait for a definite period, you can induce **`ExplicitWait`** i.e **`WebDriverWait`** with proper **`ExpectedConditions`** clause as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait_4_link = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,10));
    if(wait_4_link.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe("your_intended_url")))
    {
        //Your Test Code
    }
    else
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

> As an alternative instead of the `ExpectedConditions` clause as **`UrlToBe`** you can also use either of the following clauses :

```
wait_4_link.until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains("your_url_fraction"));
wait_4_link.until(ExpectedConditions.UrlMatches("regex_pattern_of_url"));
```